# Changing directory with perl's TokeParser

Tags: html, perl, parsing, web-crawler

How can I change the directory TokeParser looks when opening a file for parsing (e.g. adding a directory before $htmlFileName)?

```
my $p = HTML::TokeParser->new($htmlFileName);
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the directory in Perl :

```
chdir($dir);
```

`perldoc` said :

```
chdir EXPR
chdir FILEHANDLE
chdir DIRHANDLE
chdir   Changes the working directory to EXPR, if possible.  If EXPR is omitted, changes to the directory specified by $ENV{HOME}, if set; if not, changes to the directory specified by
        $ENV{LOGDIR}.  (Under VMS, the variable $ENV{SYS$LOGIN} is also checked, and used if it is set.)  If neither is set, "chdir" does nothing.  It returns true on success, false
        otherwise.  See the example under "die".

            On systems that support fchdir(2), you may pass a filehandle or directory handle as the argument.  On systems that don't support fchdir(2), passing handles raises an exception.
```

**NOTE**

another solution is to put the full path in `$htmlFileName`

Answer (score 1):

```
my $p = HTML::TokeParser->new("/foo/bar/$htmlFileName")
    or die $!;
```